# opt.apply_gradients() returns 'Trying to update a Tensor' error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

my problem is the following: Given a deep learning model and a loss function, I would like to evaluate the gradient of the loss function with respect to the input of the model and then to update the input accordingly.

The way I tried to solve this problem is very similar to the one of this tutorial, "[Writing a training loop from scratch](https://keras.io/guides/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch/)"; I had to change the variables with respect to which the gradient is evaluated and then `.apply_gradients()` is applied.

Here comes my code:

```
target = 0.5 * np.ones(data1.shape)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)

epochs = 180

for epoch in range(epochs):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    data1 = tf.convert_to_tensor(data1)
    tape.watch(data1)
    logits = pred_block(data1, training=False)
    loss_value = tf.keras.losses.MSE(target, logits)
  grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, data1)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, data1))
```

Inside the `GradientTape()` scope `data1` is converted to a tensor and then is watched by tape because otherwise I cannot take the gradient with respect to `data1`.

However, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in apply_grad_to_update_var(var, grad)
    592       """Apply gradient to variable."""
    593       if isinstance(var, ops.Tensor):
--> 594         raise NotImplementedError("Trying to update a Tensor ", var)
    595 
    596       apply_kwargs = {}

NotImplementedError: ('Trying to update a Tensor ', <tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([0.30344828, 0.30344828, 0.30344828, 0.        , 0.        ])>)
```

The tensor which it is reffering to is `data1`, hence I tried to convert it to a `numpy.array`. The last row of the code is modified as:

```
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, np.array(data1)))
```

But I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in _prepare(self, var_list)
    782         var_devices = var._devices   # pylint: disable=protected-access
    783       else:
--> 784         var_devices = [var.device]
    785       var_dtype = var.dtype.base_dtype
    786       for var_device in var_devices:

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'device'
```

The very same happens if I convert also `grads`.

I thought it may be related to the shape of `data1`, namely `(5756,5)`, because the error gives `NotImplementedError: ('Trying to .... shape = (5,))`, so I tried to add a dimension to `data1`. Before opening the `for` loop:

```
data1 = data1[:, np.newaxis, :] 

for epoch in range(epochs):
    ...
```

But the same error message kicks in:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in apply_grad_to_update_var(var, grad)
    592       """Apply gradient to variable."""
    593       if isinstance(var, ops.Tensor):
--> 594         raise NotImplementedError("Trying to update a Tensor ", var)
    595 
    596       apply_kwargs = {}

NotImplementedError: ('Trying to update a Tensor ', <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[0.30344828, 0.30344828, 0.30344828, 0.        , 0.        ]])>)
```

Even changing the `training` flag from `False` to `True` gives the same error.

I also tried to change the last two lines of the code as follows:

```
  grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, data1)
  grads = tf.distribute.get_replica_context().all_reduce('sum', grads)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, data1), 
                            experimental_aggregate_gradients=False)
```

Again, the very same error message kicks in:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py in apply_grad_to_update_var(var, grad)
    592       """Apply gradient to variable."""
    593       if isinstance(var, ops.Tensor):
--> 594         raise NotImplementedError("Trying to update a Tensor ", var)
    595 
    596       apply_kwargs = {}

NotImplementedError: ('Trying to update a Tensor ', <tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([0.30344828, 0.30344828, 0.30344828, 0.        , 0.        ])>)
```

Is there something wrong that I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update you input, it should be a `tf.Variable`, not a Tensor. The [documentation of `apply_gradients` of the optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#apply_gradients) states :

> Apply gradients to variables.

You can read more about `tf.Variable` in the guide : [Introduction to Variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variable)

Replacing your data1 Tensor with a Variable should do the job :

```
target = 0.5 * np.ones(data1.shape)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1e-3)

epochs = 180
# the Variable must be created out out of the training loop
data_variable = tf.Variable(data1)


for epoch in range(epochs):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(data_variable)
    logits = pred_block(data_variable, training=False)
    loss_value = tf.keras.losses.MSE(target, logits)
  grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, data_variable)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([grads], [data_variable]))
```

Comment: However I get a problem with zip, it seems like `data_variable` is not iterable. It is of type `tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable` @Lescurel

Comment: I forgot about that, I edited my answer, it should work for you now.

Comment: I get another error: `InvalidArgumentError: var and delta do not have the same shape[5756,5] [5] [Op:ResourceApplyGradientDescent]`, but writing `optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([grads], [data_variable]))` seems to solve it. What do you think? @Lescurel

Comment: @Omnia your last code is correct. Alternatively, use tape.gradient(loss_value, [data_variable]), then the gradient will be returned in a 1-element list and you can zip the gradient lsit and the variable list together.